# How do I find results from a certain day of the week?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering how I can query the results of a database starting on a specific day of the week?

For instance, if an order was created on a Monday and has a date field. How can I query all orders made that week beginning with Monday?

Example -

```
from orders
where orders.date_created like "%u";
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
FROM orders AS o1
JOIN orders AS o2 
  ON YEARWEEK(o2.date_created, 1) = YEARWEEK(o1.date_created, 1)
WHERE o1.order_id = ?
```

See [YEARWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) documentation.